# Translating child theme?

Tags: multisite, child-theme, translation

Parent theme directory: `blablator`, child theme directory: `blablator-child`

Network sites; two different child and parent themes. Both `.po` and `.mo` are in child directories' `/languages` folders.

Added to both child functions:

```
function my_child_theme_locale() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'blablator', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_locale' );
```

Changed in sites, and in network language to Bosnian. `.po` and `.mo` are set to `bs_BA`.

Not working! Why?

**Update:**

I don't want to override (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/override) anything.

My translation exist only in childs theme "language" folder.

I don't mix any strings, or I want strings from childs to work with parent.

I have no idea what "Translating child theme", has to do with "Override parent 
theme translation on child theme", except that I tried same function to acomplish different or similar task.

It is as if someone asked "What is WordPress", and any other question about WordPress would be duplicate, because it is about WordPress.

Delete question if its duplicate, I'm off this community anyway.

Comment: What does `load_child_theme_textdomain` return? `true` or `false`?